# Route prepared statements to the slaves

Tags: mariadb, maxscale

My setup is as the following:
MaxScale 2.1.4 -> Master -> 2 slaves (both MariaDB 10.2). *CentOS 7

Most of my queries are prepared statements so the master basically handles 90% of the queries right now.

I've enabled the hintfilter and tried to add a hint to a query:

```
/* maxscale route to server server2 */
```

Unfortunately, it still ends up on the master.

I understood that MaxScale 2.2 should introduce some auto solution for prepared statements. However, I need some temp solution(I'll try to look into ProxySQL if none is found).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it inside a transaction?  If so, let's see the whole transaction.

Comment: Just a single SQL statement (a simple one actually just as a test).
Anyway, I've moved on to ProxySQL and it looks fantastic so far. Will revisit MaxScale once it's more complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the `mysql` command line client to test it, remember to enable SQL comments by using the `-c` flag.

Since MaxScale 2.0.1, the hint mechanism will override any decisions taken by the router itself if the router supports hints. The *readwritesplit* and *schemarouter* routers are currently the only routers that support routing hints so make sure you are using one of these routers.